# How to use the google calendar watch api method in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm developing a flutter app that integrates google calendar functionalities.
I'm using the googleapis package to insert/get/delete calendars and events.
My question is how to use the "watch" method to get notifications if a calendar or event has changed?
I looked it up on the internet but there are no clear documentations or tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

The watch method is an API method that accepts a POST request. You create a subscription channel, supplying a web-hook URL where the notifications will be sent. See https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#overview